# Group collection by month and type user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a collection of invoices and to make a chart from it I want to group them in months and in those months a subdivision by the type of the user.

If I group by month or group by user type separately they work but if I want to group them by month and in that month by the user type it's not working.

Vue

```
const invoices = await this.$http.get('/invoices/stats', {
  params: {
    with: 'user,customer,extension',
    start: this.startDate,
    end: this.endDate,
  }
})
```

Laravel

```
public function stats(Request $request)
{
    $result = Invoice::with(explode(',', $request->with))
      ->scopes(['period'])
      ->get()
      ->groupBy(function ($q) {
          return Carbon::parse($q->date)->format('m');
      })
      ->groupBy('user.type');

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the `$result` array/collection? I am already thinking about Multiple grouping criteria See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin  [
        {
          id: 1,
          date: "2019-01-01",
          total: 500,
          user {
            type: "freelancer"
          }
        }
      ]

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin They're grouped by user type but I want to group them first by month. How I can accomplish that?

Comment: Try it:
->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(date)"))

Comment: @JoaoGRRR I already found to group them by month and to group them by user type. If I put them together they not work as I would want.

Comment: If you mean 'groupBy' date, then usertype in hierarchy e.g `month`->`user.type` then that's possible too. Let me know if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
// group by user types
$user_types = Invoice::with(explode(',', $request->with))
  ->scopes(['byMonth'])
  ->orderBy('date')
  ->get()
  ->groupBy('user.type');

// group the user types by month
// (double groupBy is not possible in 1 query)
foreach ($user_types as $key => $value) {
  $user_types_by_month[$key] = $value->groupBy(function ($q) {
    return Carbon::parse($q->date)->format('m');
  });
}

// calculate the total by month by user types and replace the array with the total
foreach ($user_types_by_month as $i => $types) {
  foreach ($types as $j => $months) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($months as $m) {
      $total += $m->total;
    }
    $user_types_by_month[$i][$j] = $total;
  }
}
return $user_types_by_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, i do not think you can do multiple groupby on a collection. Just did a quick test and it does not work on my side.

I think you have 2 options:

- Do a query for each month, group each result collection by user type then you will merge the collections (basically). but you will do more queries.
- If you just need counts to display charts you can do all of that with multiple group by on an SQL query, outside Eloquent. 
  It would look like :

```
    Select count(*), YEAR(i.date), MONTH(i.date), u.type 
    from invoice i left join user u on i.user_id = u.id 
    group by MONTH(i.date), YEAR(i.date), u.type
```

Keep in mind the kind of data you need is a bit out of scope regarding what Eloquent is meant to be used for.